# Can each class have an __init__() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am learning Python and I have a situation in which I am tempted to have an `__init__()` function in several of my different classes.  Are there any problems that this could cause?  If it makes any difference one of them is in a Tkinter main loop for the user interface.

Thanks.

Comment: It is unusual for a class to lack an init method.

Comment: Every class has an `__init__` method. You either define it yourself or inherit it.

Comment: The only thing one has to take into account is that very often (not always) one has to call the `super().__init__()` with the right parameters. Otherwise the base class does not get control to initialize that part of the object correctly. Furthermore except for some overhead (control passing through the entire MRO of `__init__`s, no there is not really a problem).

Comment: Try to create a class without defining an `__init__` method, and then instantiating it and calling .__init__ on the instantiated object. The expectation is that if you do not define it yourself it should not exist, right? It will be instructive.

Comment: What is MRO?...

Comment: @EPo Method Resolution Order. It's a list of superclasses. When you write `spam.eggs`, if `spam` doesn't have an `eggs`, and `type(spam)` doesn't have an `eggs`, Python looks through each class in `type(spam).mro()` until one of _them_ has an `eggs`. The reason it's a thing that needs a name and a special method in Python is that Python allows multiple inheritance with shared bases, so it needs [a clever algorithm](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) to make `super` work without repetition.

Comment: Okay so if I am understanding correctly then each time that I create an `__init__` method and declare as `__init__(self):` I am also creating an instance of the variable `self`.  Do these instances of `self` remain independent of one another?

Comment: No, the *instance* itself is already constructed. If you write `type(some, parameters)`, and there is no meta-class that prevents it, Python will allocate memory for the object, and then pass control to the `__init__` of that type with `self` the object constructed, and the parameters are passed to the `__init__` call such that it can do proper *initialization*.

Comment: Working through an introductory tutorial on writing classes will help answer many of these questions.

Comment: @Prune Do you have a recommendation for a good tutorial on this?  I have been doing Lynda.com tutorials but I don't feel that I've found one covering this well enough.

Comment: That's beyond Stack Overflow's range.  Try a browser search for "Python class tutorial"; there should be something in the first page that matches your learning style and preferred level of writing.

Comment: `__init__` is basically the same as every other special method, like `__repr__` or `__hash__`. Special methods get called automatically by Python (in this case, after the object is constructed, Python calls its `__init__` method), but once they're called, they're the same as any other method—including the way `self` gets passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `__init__()` does is allowing you to set up the initial values inside your class, either as hard-coded default values or as values you pass the object as parameters. Imagine you having to have a class Employee and 10 Employee objects in your code. In theory you could do without having an **init**() and set the various fields (e.g., name, wage, and so on) from outside your class... But why would you, if you can have this handy little function that does all of that for you?

Comment: You need to fix the formatting of your answer, \__init__ is showing up as __init__, which makes your answer hard to read.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can escape the autoformatting of double underscores?